# extract JavaTree Item Color using QTP

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I am working on JavaTree Item in `QTP`.
I am finding method to get color, Font Style (Bold, Strikethrough) of JavaTree Item.
But i am not getting anything.
One method is there,

```
JavaWindow("Collaborative Product").JavaTree("NavTree").Object.getItem(0).getData().isMarkupNode()
```

which returns `False` if the item is strikethru else returns `True`.
But not getting anything for Bold and color.
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: It´s pretty impossible to answer this since the method or "whatever" to query is totally dependent on the AUT. Talk to the developers. They can show you Java code that they would use to query the color from within the app. Using that code, you have a good chance to get a solution here.